# Jquery datepicker not viewable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I an using JQuery datepicker on my asp.net page and I can't see "Prev" or "Next" buttons but I can click on them.  Where can I change the color of these buttons or make them viewable?  I tried with other themes, but still same result.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the downloaded theme, make sure that the images in the theme are in the right location.  Otherwise maybe they're being hidden by one of the css classes you have.  Here's the html that the plugin generates:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w">Prev</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">Next</span>
```

Comment: When I add the CSS files, do I also need to import the images to my project? How do you check that the images in the theme are in the right location?

Comment: @Tony: use firebug to inspect the next or prev button. In your css panel, you should see a line containing `url('some/path/prev.png')`, this path is relative to the location of your css file, and it's the place where the images should be. Or you could just open datepicker.css, and search for `.ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e` and there look for `url('some/path/prev.png')`

Comment: Yep, the theme's css file should tell you where the images are supposed to be in the 2nd .ui-icon selector, something like: .ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); }.  The jQuery UI prev and next buttons are sprite background positions being referenced in the ./images folder relative to the css file if you downloaded the theme from building your theme on http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: Ah, got it.  I was referencing the images outside of the folder relative to the css file.  I changed to correct folder, it works now.  Thanks both of you for help!